# Trying to add href on a PHP code - Syntax Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add an href link on a php code.

Here's the code:

```js
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["month"]."/".$row["day"]."/".$row["year"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["empname"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["position"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["platform"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["processor"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["ram"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["monitor"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["phonetype"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["headset"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
    <td>'.<a href="records.php?reqnumber=<?php echo $row_message['reqnumber']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a>.'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
```

So I'm having problems specifically with `<td>'.<a href="records.php?reqnumber=<?php echo $row_message['reqnumber']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a>.'</td>`

As you can see I tried adding `'.` and `.'` but for some reason I'm getting the syntax error.

Comment: Color coding should be your first clue. And then you have mixed open/close php with concatenation, which is never good. This just looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake starting with `<td>'.<a href="r`
it should be

`<td><a href="records.php?reqnumber='.$row_message['reqnumber'] .'">`

Here's the corrected format

```
 <?php

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["month"]."/".$row["day"]."/".$row["year"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["empname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["position"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["platform"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["processor"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["ram"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["monitor"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phonetype"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["headset"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
            <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber='.$row_message['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
echo $output;
```